# MVC Beta 1 Routing - what number of routes will start to cause performance issues?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am considering pre-loading routes to static content pages, allowing for n-depth nesting of content. I have a solution spiked that provides a bit of comfort in terms of the number of potential routes registered, but I'm wondering if I'm making the system overly complex.

At what number of registered routes do you suspect a basic hosting account would start to suffer in performance? These routes are pure-text, with no need to parse values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route-parsing, compared with database access? I would guess the route-parsing is pretty cheap. Until you get into the thousands of routes.